# Show row of query even if not exists mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query in which I return an average of a salary for each of the categories.  The point is that some categories only have salary in Q and not in $ and I want to show both even if $ not exists.

My query is this:

```
SELECT a.name, m.symbol, FORMAT(ROUND(AVG(c.salary)), 0) AS total
FROM people c
JOIN documentation cd
ON c.idpeople = cd.People_idpeople
JOIN cate_people cc
ON cc.id_docu = cd.id_docu
JOIN area a
ON a.idarea = cc.idcategory
JOIN coin m
ON m.id_coin = c.coin
WHERE c.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
AND c.salary < 50000
AND cd.fk_alliance = 1
GROUP BY cc.idcategory, m.id_coin;
```

Giving this result:

```
-----------------------------
|Systems ---- Q ------ 4,514 |
|Systems ---- $ ------ 300   |
|Learng ----- Q ------ 3,551 |
|Admin ------ Q ------ 4,027 |
|Admin ------ $ ------ 2,438 |
-----------------------------
```

How can I make Learng show a $ column but with a zero value?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Your group by does not make too much sense because none of those fields are in the select list. Therefore your query is most likely against the sql standards and would run in mysql under specific sql mode setting only

Comment: So how can I make my query to achieve what I want without being against sql standars?